# Draft Defaults: Common Baseline Stats

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building, mtg-drafting

I don't really draft at all.

My general question: In the scope of new sets (non-supplemental), what are generally good cards to draft?

Specifics:

-What P/T is good for a beater of X CMC? How many would I want/need?

-What P/T is good for an evasion creature of X CMC? How many would I want/need?

-What CMC is good for spot removal? How many would I want/need?

-What CMC is good for burn spells of X damage? How many would I want/need?

-What P/T and abilities/ability words are good for a bomb of X CMC?

-What kind of card draw/tutors are good at X CMC?

-What kind of disruption (counters, discard, combat tricks) is good at X CMC?

-How much mana should I be spending on different kinds of 2-for-1's? (ETB with removal/disruption, token generation, etc.)

-Of 2 or more optimal/preferred cards, which is the better pick?

-Is the BREAD strategy ("Bombs, Removal, Evasion, Advantage, Dudes" prioritized in that order) viable?

I realize that each cycle and block has different results for each of these questions. Feel free to use examples from any block with supporting pools as to why X card helps Y card. I love specific card references.

Comment: There's very broad and variable answers to this: this is a *lot* of analysis, and in the Standard format, what marks good value for mana varies. Some Standard rotations have more powerful or less powerful creatures and destruction; e.g. Innistrad/Return to Ravnica was regarded as a fairly fast format, while things were observably slowed down over the course of RTR/Theros and Theros/KTK.

Comment: This isn't about standard. This is about draft.

I'm not looking for every response to answer every question. I just don't know how to pull worthy cards in a draft. The questions I asked weren't asked to be answered specifically, but I know that those categories are common factors in drafting. I don't know what's too expensive for a beater, removal, burn, flyer, etc., and I certainly don't know how to distinguish between the better of two preferred cards.

Comment: @Shankensteinium To answer this question would take a few blog posts on how to draft.  Something with that long of an answer isn't really appropriate for this site.

Comment: Again, I'm not looking for each response to answer every question. Inputs with one or two examples are fine. I was specifically asking here because sites like Reddit and MTGSalvation are blocked in this AOR, even in the tents. But, so be it. I'll ask there when I'm stateside.